# Alternative for runat = server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Is there any alternative for `runat ="server"` in vb.net code. I am not supposed to use `runat="server"`

```
Protected name As String = " "
<script  language ="VB" runat="server">
    Actual code here 
    name&= (DTName.Rows(DRCount)("Client Name").Tostring() & "<br/>")
</script>

<html>
   <%=name%>
</html>
```

If I don't use `runat="server"`,the code in html does not get displayed.

Comment: The code is Not supposed to have runat="server" or <asp> tags or javascript..Tats the specification given...Is thr any alternate method to do it..

Comment: Is this a riddle? Tell the person who told you no server-side code and no javascript... that they are doing it wrong.

Comment: Yes there is an alternative if you can do code-behind, as you can find elements by their ID and change them. Are you allowed code-behind?

Comment: @mike:Can use code  behind..:)